# DataCache operation - validate success

Tags: c#, caching, azure, azure-caching, shared-cache

in Windows Azure Shared Cache:
suppose I do the following:

```
try
{
  mCache.Remove(key);
  Trace.WriteLine("removed successfully from Azure Shared Cache");
}
catch (DataCacheException e)
{
  WorkerRole.log.Info(e.ToString());
}
```

is it right to say that if the code reached to the `Trace.WriteLine` command, then the operation completed successfully? (otherwise, it would be throwing `DataCacheException`.

I know I can register to the event `CacheOperationCompleted`, but is my code can be a good alternative to test operation success? (for Put/Remove methods).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Remove` method returns `boolean` flag indicating whether an item identified by the given `key`has been removed (`true`) or not (`false`).

So if you want to check operation result I would suggest following approach:

```
if(mCache.Remove(key))
{
    Trace.WriteLine("removed successfully from Azure Shared Cache");
}
```

As far as `Put` method is concerned, this might be a bit more complicated.

Basically, if your `cache.Put(key, value)` method completes successfully (no exceptions), you can assume your item has been added to your cache.

However, Azure cache items can be *evicted* from the cache (that depends on the cache size and item expiration time - default item expiration time is 48 hours for shared caching)

So in order to avoid any "*surprises*" I would recommend cache usage pattern as follows:

- Get item from cache by a key
- If cache return *Null* then create that item and put it into the cache
- Perform operation on the item

Also as a side note, I would recommend using in-role caching instead of shared caching service (mostly because it is cheaper, has more features etc.).